# handlebars properties not working

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm using the handlebars own example to get this working but apparently properties are not passet to the template

```
var source = "<p>Hello, my name is {{name}}. I am from {{hometown}}. I have " +
         "{{kids.length}} kids:</p>" +
         "<ul>{{#kids}}<li>{{name}} is {{age}}</li>{{/kids}}</ul>";
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var data = { "name": "Alan", "hometown": "Somewhere, TX",
         "kids": [{"name": "Jimmy", "age": "12"}, {"name": "Sally", "age": "4"}]};
var result = template(data);
```

the result variable is:

```
<p>Hello, my name is . I am from . I have  kids:</p><ul></ul>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I am using express-handlebars as a view engine in Node, I didn't think it would be relevant. But the solution is to add a \ in front of all of the client's {{